# Refresh Identity Cookie claims after user makes changes to profile with openiddict

Tags: cookies, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, openiddict

I'm building an app that will use openiddict and asp.net core identity for my identity server and the client is a Blazor WASM BFF app.

I've opted to use cookies for the Blazor app for security purposes. Now I've run into one snag being the fact that if a change is made to some field on the user. This field is added as a claim to the cookie and token and shows correctly when I login, however I'm not sure how to update this value in the cookie when I refresh my tokens or after the user has made the change to their profile.

I believe that the changes value is correct when I use my refresh token to get a new access token but I'm not sure how to have the change reflect in the cookie claims.

My cookie life span is linked to my access token life span.

Answer (score 0):

By default, changes to the user profile will not be reflected in OAuth tokens until the next issuance, eg if the user logs out then back in again.

One way to deal with this is to return profile information to UIs on demand, where the backend provides an API endpoint for the frontend. This forwards the access token to the OAuth user info endpoint, then returns the payload to the UI.

This is the option I prefer, since it also keeps personally identifiable information (PII) out of tokens that might otherwise be used in the browser, eg in logout redirects.

Comment: Thanks Gary, I understand the concept and my plan is to refresh the tokens(id and access) once the change is made. But my issue is with updating the cookie at the same time so that my cookie identity matches my token identity to show the new info e.g. roles or groups etc.

Comment: @Steve how did you end up handling this? struggling with the same issue

Comment: If you want to rewrite cookies in a way that is initiated by JavaScript code in the browser you can use [code like this](https://github.com/curityio/dotnet-openid-connect-webapp/blob/main/TokenClient.cs). Changing the tolen claims may not be possible though, since that may require a new user login (the delegation).

Comment: @RyanSangha Your best bet will be to have a redirect to a actual page that will render on the server and return a view, have a javascript function that will redirect you back to the original page.

But this also has it's flaws. What I suggest you do it only keep the users id and maybe some static claims in the cookie, and have a middle ware read the claims/security info from a cache using the static data in the cookie. be sure to invalidate your cache when changes are made. Your cookie should be secure, so have a userinfo endpoint that return the claims to your UI for Authorisation

Comment: @RyanSangha For the cookie to be updated, you will need some sort of page reload for the cookie to be served from the server, if you have updated it from a token refresh.