# Identity Server - Refresh Cookie with User Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have 3 applications:
Identity Server,
Api,
Web Client (Razor).

The whole setup is in such a way where the api only cares about an access token (which has nickname and country as claims), through AddJWTBearer.

The Web client is using Cookies and connects to the identity server.

My Identity Server has an endpoint to update some user profile fields (think nickname, country).

Identity Server is issuing these claims when asked for an ApiScope, so that these claims get in the access token not identity token.

I have a scenario where my razor client is updating the profile through my idsvr user endpoint. However now my cookie (and more importantly the access token inside my cookie) are out of date as it has the old claims for nickname and country.

I would like my razor client to issue a new cookie with the new access token inside it.

Any Ideas how I should go about this?

I am aware I can use the refresh token to get a new access token, however this won't refresh my cookie.

Code samples - Razor WebClient:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:44302";

    options.ClientId = "web";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    options.SaveTokens = true;

    options.Scope.Clear();
    options.Scope.Add("openid");
    options.Scope.Add("profile");
    options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
    options.Scope.Add("IdentityServerApi");

    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    options.ClaimActions.MapAll();
})
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = async x =>
        {
            if (x.HttpContext != null &&
                x.HttpContext.User != null &&
                x.HttpContext.User.Identity != null)
            {
                var now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
                var timeElapsed = now.Subtract(value: x.Properties.IssuedUtc!.Value);
                var timeRemaining = x.Properties.ExpiresUtc!.Value.Subtract(now);

                if (timeElapsed > timeRemaining)
                {
                    using var discoveryHttpClient = new HttpClient();

                    var discoveryResponse = await discoveryHttpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:44302");
                    if (discoveryResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(discoveryResponse.Error);
                    }

                    if (x.Principal != null)
                    {
                        if (x.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                        {
                            var accessTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst("access_token");
                            var refreshTokenClaim = identity.FindFirst("refresh_token");

                            var tokenClient = new HttpClient();

                            var refreshTokenEndpoint = discoveryResponse.TokenEndpoint ?? string.Empty;

                            tokenClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(refreshTokenEndpoint);

                            var refreshToken = refreshTokenClaim?.Value ?? string.Empty;

                            var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestRefreshTokenAsync(new RefreshTokenRequest()
                            {
                                ClientId = "web",
                                ClientSecret = "secret",
                                GrantType = "refresh_token",
                                RefreshToken = refreshToken
                            });

                            if (tokenResponse != null &&
                            !tokenResponse.IsError &&
                            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenResponse.AccessToken) &&
                            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tokenResponse.RefreshToken))
                            {
                                identity.RemoveClaim(accessTokenClaim);
                                identity.RemoveClaim(refreshTokenClaim);

                                identity.AddClaims(new[]
                                {
                                new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken),
                                new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken)
                            });
                                x.ShouldRenew = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
```

---

Update:
My aim is to refresh the cookie on my razor client, once from the razor client i hit my custom endpoint in idsvr to update profile.
My Access token should always store the latest information (nickname and country), so that the api can function through these.

Comment: You are not supposed to look inside the access token in your razor app. Use the identity token instead.

Comment: And you can retrieve user information if you hit the `[issuer-url]/userinfo` url

Comment: Why not?
I understand what you mean, however this information is also required by the api which only uses a bearer token (access token). Since I cannot pass the identity token (and i believe its not recomended aswell), the only solution is to issue a new cookie so that my razor can connect to the api with the new access token containing the new details.

Comment: The API is fine, because the access token is destined to it. but your client app shouldn't look into it.

Comment: ok so then how do I force my razor client to get a new cookie/access token, so that when the user updates his user profile then calls an api endpoint, the nickname and country are updated correctly for the api to function?

Comment: I would preferably like to use this information from the claims. The whole idea for me to store this data in claims is so that I dont have to do a db call or an idsvr call to user endpoint each time i need this metadata.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016825/refresh-identity-cookie-claims-after-user-makes-changes-to-profile-with-openiddi

Comment: @Style can you also check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870309/refresh-user-cookie-ticket-in-asp-net-core-identity/41872895#41872895. Maybe you can have a redirect from idsrvr after you update the profile to a page in your razor pages app that will refresh the token?

Comment: @Abdelkrim thanks for helping ! I actually came across that post in my research but became confused as not sure whether the suggested logic should be applied to idsvr solution or my client solution.
Any ideas?

Comment: @Abdelkrim If I make an endpoint to refresh my token, how will i then issue a new cookie

Comment: Hey @Style after spending some time on this, I think the only solution you have in hand is to signout the user when he is redirected back from the IdentityServer (after making the change) and after the signout, redirect them to a page that needs authorization, this will make a quick roundtrip to the identity server and will refresh to cookies. If you want to do this, I can write a proper answer for it.

Comment: Of course, if the session on identity server has expired (which I doubt, since, the user was there doing the nickname change) the user needs to re-authenticate. But other than that, the redirection will be smooth and the user can't even notice it.

Comment: Hey man! Thanks for your tips, I actually did something similiar to what you suggested.
After the user updates the profile, he is redirected to a RefreshCookie path.
I then used the same code which handles expiring cookie/access token to refresh the cookie/tokens when user hits the refresh cookie path.
The Refresh cookie page then just redirects to wherever he originally was, with new cookie/access/refresh tokens. Posting code as an answer.